# dplyr: want to add only 1 y column during a join, not all y columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to join a table with itself in order to realize inheritance of a value in one column, as follows:
There are two types of rows, `base` and `dep` (for "dependent").
All rows have a `key`, but `dep` rows also have a `basekey` referring to a `base` row. There is a column `val` and any number of other columns.

**My goal:** Obtain all `dep` rows, with their `val` replaced by the `val` of the corresponding `base` row.

Here is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

tb = tribble(
    ~key, ~type, ~basekey, ~val, ~col5, ~colN,
    "a", "base", NA,       17,   1,      100,
    "b", "base", NA,       21,   4,      130,
    "d", "dep",  "a",      NA,   11,     320,
    "g", "dep",  "a",      NA,   14,     420,
    "n", "dep",  "a",      NA,   13,     230,
    "y", "dep",  "b",      NA,   66,     665
)
```

My actual data has a few hundred rows and `N=20` columns, so runtime or memory performance is not an issue, but operations requiring a complete column list should be avoided.

## sqldf

Previously, I used the `sqldf` package, which can express my requirement nicely:

```
sqldf("select tb.*, tb2.val as baseval 
       from tb, tb as tb2 
       where tb2.key = tb.basekey")
```

The result is almost exactly what I want; I only need to map `baseval` to `val` or live with the longer name (which is OK for me):

```
  key type basekey val col5 colN baseval
1   d  dep       a  NA   11  320      17
2   g  dep       a  NA   14  420      17
3   n  dep       a  NA   13  230      17
4   y  dep       b  NA   66  665      21
```

## dplyr

But then I started learning `ggplot2` and encountered the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/). 
After some reading, I decided to throw myself into its arms and rework my code according to its readable and tidy style.

`readr` and `tibble` worked like a charm, but with `dplyr` I am not yet entirely happy; my use case appears to be one that is not supported well (maybe it's just that my thinking is not taking the best route yet).

I need to do a left join, but although all I want is the `val` column, there appears to be no method (as of `dplyr` 0.7.4) for suppressing the others:

```
tbj = left_join(filter(tb, type=='dep'), tb, by=c(basekey='key'))
```

which gives me this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 11
    key type.x basekey val.x col5.x colN.x type.y basekey.y val.y col5.y colN.y
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <chr>     <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     d    dep       a    NA     11    320   base      <NA>    17      1    100
2     g    dep       a    NA     14    420   base      <NA>    17      1    100
3     n    dep       a    NA     13    230   base      <NA>    17      1    100
4     y    dep       b    NA     66    665   base      <NA>    21      4    130
```

Whew! To get what I want, I now need to

- Map `val.y` to `val`.
- Kick out all the other `*.y` columns
- Kick out `val.x`
- Rename the other `*.x` columns to remove the suffix

This sounds laborious.
How to do it best?
Is this even the right approach or is there a more `dplyr`-ish way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, how about the following approach with `dplyr`: Remove `val` from the `dep` subset, since it's empty anyway. Then, keep only `key` and `val` in the `base` subset, rename `key` to `basekey` and join. Then post-join renaming isn't needed and you don't get any extra columns.

```
tb %>% 
  filter(type=="dep") %>% select(-val) %>% 
  left_join(tb %>% filter(type=="base") %>% select(basekey=key, val))
```

> ```
>     key  type basekey  col5  colN   val
>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     d   dep       a    11   320    17
> 2     g   dep       a    14   420    17
> 3     n   dep       a    13   230    17
> 4     y   dep       b    66   665    21
> ```

Answer (score 2):

First, you join the two tables and then select the columns needed. You can take advantage of the argument `suffix` by leaving the column names of the first table unchanged. Then selecting all columns from the first table and adding the needed column from the second table: `val.y`.

All columns from the first table plus `val.y` from the second.

```
tb %>% filter(type == "dep") %>% 
  left_join(tb %>% filter(type == "base"), 
            by = c("basekey" = "key"), 
            suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  select(names(tb), "val.y")
```

**Output**:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
    key  type basekey   val  col5  colN val.y
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     d   dep       a    NA    11   320    17
2     g   dep       a    NA    14   420    17
3     n   dep       a    NA    13   230    17
4     y   dep       b    NA    66   665    21
```

All columns but column `val` from the first table , plus `val.y` from the second.

:

```
tb %>% filter(type == "dep") %>% 
  left_join(tb %>% filter(type == "base"), 
            by = c("basekey" = "key"), 
            suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  select(names(tb), -val, "val.y")
```

**Output**:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
    key  type basekey  col5  colN val.y
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     d   dep       a    11   320    17
2     g   dep       a    14   420    17
3     n   dep       a    13   230    17
4     y   dep       b    66   665    21
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how exactly one wants to match the original requirement, repairing the result `tbj` of the question's join is possible with medium effort (**Method 1**).
But a more appropriate approach may be to pre-process the tibbles some more before doing the join (**Method 2**).

## Method 1

One can use `select` to keep the special columns and *"all of the `*.x` stuff"*, but remove *"all of the `*.y` stuff"*, and then remove `val.x` and delete the `.x` suffixes; like this

```
tbjs = select(tbj, key, type=type.x, basekey, baseval=val.y,
              ends_with(".x"))
select_all(select(tbjs, -val.x), funs(sub('\\.x', '', .)))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
    key  type basekey baseval  col5  colN
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     d   dep       a      17    11   320
2     g   dep       a      17    14   420
3     n   dep       a      17    13   230
4     y   dep       b      21    66   665
```

Not super-obvious, but not too bad either.

## Method 2

One can avoid getting those many y columns in the first place by preparing the y tibble to contain only what's needed:

```
tb2 = select(tb, key, val)
tbj2 = left_join(filter(tb, type=='dep'), tb2, by=c(basekey='key'))
```

This yields a result that is only one-and-a-half columns off:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
    key  type basekey val.x  col5  colN val.y
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     d   dep       a    NA    11   320    17
2     g   dep       a    NA    14   420    17
3     n   dep       a    NA    13   230    17
4     y   dep       b    NA    66   665    21
```

Then get rid of `val.x`, rename `val.y`, and voila!:

```
tbjs2 = rename(select(tbj2, -val.x), val=val.y)

# A tibble: 4 x 6
    key  type basekey  col5  colN   val
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     d   dep       a    11   320    17
2     g   dep       a    14   420    17
3     n   dep       a    13   230    17
4     y   dep       b    66   665    21
```

As this works without `sub`, I'd say it is the more `dplyr`-like solution.
Also, when the data gets large it will be more efficient, because the intermediate tibble is much smaller.